# Insert an event in google calendar from a website with INPUT POST

Tags: google-calendar-api

On my localhost, i'm trying to communicate with google calendar api.
Php, json, composer are installed.

From the terminal, i can list the 10 next events from my google calendar.
I found as well how to get authorised to insert a new event and i can add the event.

**My question is, how is it possible to display my event list on a webpage and add an event from a webpage with an INPUT & POST?**

**The main goal would be:**
visitor type a date, the app would check if i'm available, and if it is, it would automatically insert the event into my google calendar.

Do you have any idea for that?

I installed request for php (https://github.com/rmccue/Requests)
But it tells me that i need the authentication to access the api. How could I authenticate with request?

Thank you for your help.
Jean-Charles

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and available to do. You can start by checking out the documentation of [Google Calendar API for PHP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#prerequisites). What you would want to do is just to retrieve and be able to post/update events. This can be achieved by making GET and POST HTTP requests through the API.

As an example, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#examples) to check out how to retrieve events. The requests will return an [Event Resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) in JSON format which you can use in your web application. For creating events, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request) to make a function that makes HTTP POST requests to add or create an event.

You need to setup Oauth authentication first for you to be able to access the API. This is important and almost mandatory for all development that uses Google APIs. You probably haven't set this one up yet since you are encountering authentication problems. You can check out how to setup Oauth in PHP over [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

Comment: Dear Swagbomb,Thank you for you answer. I now know that i need to do the http request. I'm stuck with that. I've searched how to make http request with REST, but still, i don't find how to do it with this oauth2. I've made it works on localhost and running my terminal. I just don't know how to make it work on a webpage :/